# Impala DATE FORMAT

Tags: impala

I have a impala table where report_date column values are stored in yyyyMMdd and yyyy-MM-dd  string format, e.g.

20210923
2021-09-23

I want to convert them into DATE FORMAT

I tried below two commands to change the data type of the column from string to date

`CAST(report_date  AS DATE FORMAT 'yyyy-MM-dd')`

`CAST((CAST(CONCAT_WS('-',substr(repport_date,1,4),substr(repport_date,5,2),substr(repport_date,7)) AS STRING)) AS DATE FORMAT 'yyyy-MM-dd')`

And this is working fine in one environment but throwing error in other environment.

Is there any other way to change string columns to date.

If anyone could suggest a way to achieve this!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code

```
select trunc(to_timestamp( replace(your_col,'-',''),'yyyyMMdd'),'DD') date
```

This will replace - with blank first so yyyy-MM-dd gets converted to yyyyMMdd. Then use to_timestamp to make it a timestamp. Finally use trunc to remove time part and make it a date.